# WPF putting message

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to put message using label on common form. Regarding code below, I'd like to see all messages, that I'm trying to put, but I see just message after Sleep().

```
lbStatus.Content = "Synchronizing Customers";
Thread.Sleep(1000);
lbStatus.Content = "Synchronizing Estimates";

    <Label Content="" Height="28" Name="lbStatus" Margin="159,60,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" FontSize="12" Visibility="Hidden" Foreground="Blue"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue is you are sleeping on UI thread**.

After first line execution you slept on UI thread but it's UI thread responsibility to refresh UI *(UI thread refreshes UI on Render dispatcher priority)*. Hence, you see no update after first line execution because UI thread never gets time to execute render priority items queued on dispatcher.

Ideally, you should use [**DispatcherTimer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) to wait on UI thread for certain interval of time and then update once interval time is elapsed.

---

However, quick and dirty solution would be to *dispatch empty delegate on UI thread with Dispatcher priority set to Render* just before you slept on it so that UI refresh part gets executed before thread falls in sleep state.

```
lbStatus.Content = "Synchronizing Customers";
lbStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
lbStatus.Content = "Synchronizing Estimates";
```

Idea here is once you queue empty delegate on UI dispatcher with render priority, it will execute all pending items with priority higher or equal to Render. Since, UI refresh is done on on Render priority, UI will be refreshed.